# How to implement the destructive version of a String method?

Tags: ruby, string

I copied the following implementation of an `underscore` method to convert strings in camel case to strings with words separated by an underscore:

```
class String
  def underscore
    self.gsub(/::/, '/').
    gsub(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2').
    gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2').
    tr("-", "_").
    downcase
  end
end
```

How can I implement a method, say `underscore!`, to perform the same operation destructively, i.e. modifying the string in place?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`String#replace`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-replace) method:

```
class String
  def underscore
    # same as before
  end

  def underscore!
    replace(underscore)
  end
end

s = 'FooBar'
s.underscore!
puts s
# 'foo_bar'
```

Comment: @Miichi's answer is wrong. It returns `nil` under wrong conditions.

Comment: @sawa Thanks, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @sawa: Thanks for pointing that out in my answer.  I've modified my answer to return self and only in the case if any of the used !-methods returns a non-nil value.

Answer (score 4):

Basically just replace every method in your body with its ! equivalent.  However, then you also need to adjust for the fact that a ! method should return nil if it makes no change.  For example:

```
class String
    def underscore!
        if [ self.gsub!(/::/, '/'), 
             self.gsub!(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2'),
             self.gsub!(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2'),
             self.tr!("-", "_"),
             self.downcase!
           ].any?
            self        
        else
            nil
    end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [alias_method](http://wikimatze.de/method-alias-in-ruby.html)

```
class String
  def underscore
    self.gsub(/::/, '/').
    gsub(/([def underscore
    dup.underscore!
  endA-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2').
    gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2').
    tr("-", "_").
    downcase
  end

  alias_method :orig_underscore, :underscore

  def underscore!
    self.replace self.orig_underscore
  end
end
```